# How to describe details of an automatic migration

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, automatic-migration

In *Entity Framework Code-First* you can enable automatic migrations based on code changes in the model.

By calling `Update-Database`, these changes are:

1. Registered in a `[timestamp]_AutomaticMigration`
2. Generate SQL scripts and migrate database
3. Store the migration in the table __MigrationHistory

In the `__MigrationHistory` table, the migration is described in the Model column as a large hex value. eg:

```
0x1F8B0800000000000400CD57CD6EDB3810BE2FB0EF20F0B40512313F976D20B5C8CAC9C2D83A09AAB4775A1ADBC492944A5281FD6C3DF491FA0A1D...
```

In the Package Manager Console within Visual Studio, you can retrieve a list of automatic migrations with `Get-Migrations`.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the details of a particular automatic migration -- whether that's SQL script, or which model & fields are being affected.

**Is there a way that I'm unaware of to retrieve details of a particular automatic migration?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

This value in table __MigrationHistory, is a GZiped Xml, that contains the EDMX schema.

I made this following code to retrieve the EDMX model (**this code uses C# 6**)

> You can access this code on my gist also, with this link: https://gist.github.com/AlbertoMonteiro/45198dc80641ce1896e6
>
> In this gist there is a C# 5 version, that you can paste in a console application.

```cs
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO.Compression;

public void DecompressDatabaseMigration(string migrationName, string databaseName)
{
    var connectionString = $@"Data source=.\sqlexpress;Initial catalog={databaseName};Integrated security=true";
    var sqlToExecute = String.Format("select model from __MigrationHistory where migrationId like '%{0}'", migrationName);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var command = new SqlCommand(sqlToExecute, connection);

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            throw new Exception("Now Rows to display. Probably migration name is incorrect");
        }

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var model = (byte[])reader["model"];
            var decompressed = Decompress(model);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\edmx.xml", decompressed.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public XDocument Decompress(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            return XDocument.Load(gzipStream);
        }
    }
}

DecompressDatabaseMigration(Args[1], Args[0]);
```

As you can see, there is some syntax that is allowed in the new C# REPL that arrived with Visual Studio Update 1.

So I save this file with `.csx` extention and then I execute, in my case `DecompileMigration.csx`

```
csi DecompileMigration.csx
```

Then the script will put in my **C:\temp** folder the file **emdx.xml** and then I see the model in this particular migration.

To use the REPL of VS 2015 update 1, you can

### Load the customized CMD called **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015**

Press Windows and then search for this name **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015**

#### Option 1

Open this in **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015\Visual Studio Tools**

#### Option 2

Open a cmd session, and then execute this following command

```
call "%vs140comntools%vsdevcmd.bat"
```

#### Option 3

Open it in Visual Studio 2015 U1 in the menu `VIEW > Other Windows > C# Interactive`

[image: C# Interactive]

If you use this option, the `Args` member in the script will not work, so you must replace the `Args[0]` for your database name, and `Args[0]` for your database name.

Comment: Much thanks for this answer Alberto! I imagine it will help others who come across this issue and have no choice but to use automatic migrations (eg. for an existing system with migrations)

Comment: @Jono I always use manual migration, but sometime I had a problem, that I execute `Update-Database` and I received a msg that say there is no pending migration, but when I ran the code, I got a exception that model was changed. So I tried to create a new Migration, and the migration was empty, so I have to enable automatic migration, then I used that method and discovered what changed, I discovered that was a dll version was causing that. So it a nice way to "debug" the migration.

Answer (score 1):

This question came from a misunderstanding between automatic migrations vs. explicit migrations.

I considered an explicit migration would require you to write all up/down changes.

`Add-Migration` with migration changes that would otherwise be picked up by an automatic migration **are placed automatically into the explicit migration file**.

Calling `Update-Database` after the explicit migration will migrate the changes, but now with a code file detailing the changes.

Comment: Ahh I just answered how to get the details of a automatic migration